# Is it ok to use laptop on pull-out desk?

Tags: laptop

I have a bit stupid question. I have a laptop that I use on a pull-out desk. I would like to ask if it is safe to use the laptop on something like this because when I press the keyboard the desk can tilt down slightly by 1 or 2 millimeters and whether this will create vibrations that could harm the laptop.

Thank you for your answers !

Comment: As long as the laptop is secure, no harm.  Still very much an opinion depending on the condition of the shelf.

Comment: think about the environment that the laptop was designed for

Comment: People use them on their **laps**. Very depressing.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik to be fair - I don't think that's been safe for years, not for the lap rather than the PC though :D

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, it's still a hot topic and people vent on it often. Sorry, don't mean to provoke in an inflammatory manner.

Comment: Leaving laptops in an enclosed space can generate a lot of heat, especially with default W10/11 where the power button does not switch off the machine unless explicitly done in the power settings.

Answer (score 1):

As far back as the late *2000s* laptops have had systems designed to help them deal with vibrations and drops.

Consider a laptop that's on say a train or plane - an environment of *constant* vibrations. Traditional hard drives were often protected by a acceleration sensor that would park the heads on excessive acceleration AKA dropping. Modern SSDs have no moving parts. Other than the fans, there's literally no other moving parts in a modern fan, and I've never heard of a fan die of anything other than old age either.

Your *gentle* 1mm motion while typing is probably less than what a laptop would face under these conditions. Modern equipment - while harder to repair, is *astonishingly* robustly built. You shouldn't generally face issues due to regular use within the design lifespan of the machine.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: I think someone downvoted all the answers. I'm suspecting its more "this question ought not to have been answered" rather than any defect of the answer :D

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine, however there is something worth considering -

If the laptop has an HDD that will spin, and the vibration could - over time - reduce its lifespan.  If it has an SSD - which is a lot more common in laptops now - it will be fine as the only moving parts are fans - and those are not particularly sensitive devices.